# Is it possible to tell Chromium to always "keep" PDFs?

Tags: chromium, downloads, pdf, productivity

I download a lot of PDFs in Chromium and always get a warning telling me that "files of this type can harm [my] computer", which forces me to manually confirm every download. I've enabled the "always open files of this type" setting, but that's only useful for after a file has been downloaded. Any way around this warning? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Exit chromium
2. `gedit ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`
3. Locate a section that looks like:

   ```
   "download": {
     "directory_upgrade": true,
     "extensions_to_open": "",
     "prompt_for_download": false
   },
   ```
4. Change the `extensions_to_open` setting from "" to `pdf`. If there are already other extensions, use a colon to separate `pdf` from the existing entries (i.e. `foo:bar:pdf`).
5. Save the configuration file.

---

- [Source](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65895#c57)
- Untested; will delete if it is no longer a valid method (it's from 2011).

Comment: Haven't tested this yet, will update once I do. Thank you, very helpful!